# How do I use public functions from Rust files within other files

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I am new to rust and trying to figure out how to structure my projects in such a way I can use reusable components.

As an example I created a `test` project space using `cargo new test`

I created a `concat_strings.rs` , `time_request.rs` and `start_listen.rs` files.

concat_strings

```rs
pub fn concatenate_strings(strings: &[&str]) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    for s in strings {
        result.push_str(s);
        result.push(' ');
    }
    result.trim_end().to_string()
}
```

time_request

```rs
use chrono::{Local, Datelike, Timelike};

pub fn get_current_time() -> String {
    let current_time = Local::now();
    let formatted_time = format!(
        "{:04}-{:02}-{:02}/{:02}:{:02}:{:02}",
        current_time.year(),
        current_time.month(),
        current_time.day(),
        current_time.hour(),
        current_time.minute(),
        current_time.second(),
    );
    formatted_time
}
```

and the idea was that I can use concat_strings from `start_listen`

```rs
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use toml::Value;

mod start_listen;

pub fn start_listen() -> String {
    let mut file = File::open("Listen.toml").unwrap();
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();
    let value = contents.parse::<Value>().unwrap();

    let ip = value["ip"].as_str().unwrap();
    let port = value["port"].as_integer().unwrap() as u16;
}
```

While I can use the `mod` keyword just fine from `main.rs` it seems I cannot use it from other files.

```rs
mod concat_strings;
mod time_request;
mod start_listen;

fn main() {
```

Can anyone familiar with rust point out how to go about this? Thanks!

EDIT:

Doing this worked `use crate::concat_strings;`

Comment: Are you aware that your `concatenate_strings()` is just [`join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would go about this is to create a `lib.rs` file:

```
//! This is the lib.rs file
pub mod start_listen;
pub mod concat_strings;
pub mod time_request;
```

and then from `main.rs`

```
use project_name::start_listen::start_listen;
use project_name::concat_strings::concatenate_strings;
use project_name::time_request::get_current_time;

fn main() {
    start_listen();
    concatenate_strings(&["Hey", "Hiya"]);
    let time = get_current_time();
}
```

and from other files (for example you want to use `concatenate_string()` from `start_listen.rs`

```
use crate::concat_strings::concatenate_strings;

pub fn start_listen() -> String {
    concatenate_strings(&["A string", "Also a string"]);
    do_stuff!()
}
```

You could refer to the Rust book Chapter 7 for more

https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html